# How to query dates in pandas using pd.DataFrame.query()

Tags: python, pandas

When querying rows in a dataframe based on a datcolumn value, it works when comparing just the year, but not for a date.

```
fil1.query('Date>2019')
```

This works fine. However when giving complete date, it fails.

```
fil1.query('Date>01-01-2019')
#fil1.query('Date>1-1-2019')   # fails as well

TypeError: Invalid comparison between dtype=datetime64[ns] and int
```

What is the correct way to use dates on `query` function ? The [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) doesnt seem to help.

Comment: I guess you need to enclose the date between quotes: `fil1.query('Date>"01-01-2019"')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two errors in your code. Date default format is yyyy-mm-dd, and you should use "" for values.

```
fil1.query('Date>"2019-01-01"')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you filter only the year, this is probably an integer value, so this works:

`fil1.query('year > 2019')`

A full date-string must be filtered with quotation marks, e.g.

`fil1.query('date > "2019-01-01"')`

It's a bit like in SQL, there you also cannot filter like `WHERE date > 1-1-2019`, you need to do `WHERE date > '2019-01-01'`.

Answer (score 1):

Query on dates works for me

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Dates': ['2022-01-01', '2022-01-02','2022-01-03','2022-01-04']})
df
Out[101]: 
        Dates
0  2022-01-01
1  2022-01-02
2  2022-01-03
3  2022-01-04
df.query('Dates>"2022-01-02"')
Out[102]: 
        Dates
2  2022-01-03
3  2022-01-04
```